# SQL Server : Order by 1st Column grouping and ordering 2nd Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, row-number, dense-rank

I want to `ORDER BY` an integer followed by a string, but keeping together and ordered equals strings.

Example:

```
[01]  01 | N9
[02]  02 | C4
[03]  03 | C5
[04]  04 | N9
[05]  07 | C5
[06]  08 | C5
[07]  15 | U1
[08]  15 | D2
[09]  16 | N9
[10]  18 | N9
```

Desired order:

```
[01]  01 | N9
[04]  04 | N9
[09]  16 | N9
[10]  18 | N9
[02]  02 | C4
[03]  03 | C5
[05]  07 | C5
[06]  08 | C5
[08]  15 | D2
[07]  15 | U1
```

I've tried `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`, but I didn't find a correct solution

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to want:

```
select e.*
from example e
order by min(col2) over (partition by col3), col3, col2;
```

Comment: Thk. It works! Both solutions give me the desired result, but in a very large array, I guess the 2nd one assures me that Integer will be in crescendo.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
select * from <table> order by min(col2) over (partition by col3 order by col2)
```